# Update table using dynamically determined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySql server in my current project and need help to provide a migration. I have a table 'Patterns' with a field 'title' and a new field named 'alias',which value is NULL for all the rows. I need to write in this field using next algorithm:

```
1) if title field is unique: just write it's value in alias
2) if title is not unique: alias = title +'-'+ n , where n is number of  occurrence
```

For example:

```
________________

|id|title|alias
|1 |smile|null
|2 |smile|null
|3 |smile|null
________________
```

should be transformed to:

```
 ________________

 |id|title|alias
 |1 |smile|smile
 |2 |smile|smile-1
 |3 |smile|smile-2
 ________________
```

Is it possible to achieve such result using SQL, thank you in advance for help

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results (although it is pretty clear, that is a good habit).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain in MySQL.  You can do it using variables.

```
select t.*,
       (case when tt.cnt > 1 then concat(t.title, '-', rn) else t.title end) as new_title
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = title, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := title, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := '') params
      order by title
     ) t join
     (select title, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by title
     ) tt
     on tt.title = t.title;
```

In many cases, you can leave out the "-1" on a singleton. That simplifies the query:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rn > 1 then concat(t.title, '-', rn) else t.title end) as new_title
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = title, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := title, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := '') params
      order by title
     ) t ;
```